# Transaction reverted when calling swapExactTokensForTokens function, web3py, Python

Tags: python, blockchain, web3py

I'm trying to perform swap via Pancakeswap router contract.
Here is my code:

```
def swapTokens():
amountIn = (w3.toWei(0.00001,'ether')) 
amount1  = contractR.functions.getAmountsOut(amountIn, path).call()
amountOutMin = int(amount1[1] *0.9) 
minAmountPrint = w3.fromWei(amountOutMin, 'ether')
print('Minimum recieved:',minAmountPrint)
swap_TX = contractR.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
amountIn,
amountOutMin,
path,
myAccount,
(int(time.time()) + 1000000)
).buildTransaction({
'from': myAccount,
'value': w3.toWei(0.0001,'ether'),
'gas': 550000,
'gasPrice': w3.toWei('5','gwei'),
'nonce': nonce,
})
signed_TX = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(swap_TX, private_key = privateKey)
tx_token = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_TX.rawTransaction)
print(w3.toHex(tx_token))
print('Your current balance:',w3.fromWei(w3.eth.get_balance(myAccount), 'ether'), 'BNB')
```

But transaction fails every time with error "Execution reverted"
Reverted transactions hashes:
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc3763879d31b34439e023e3dea2bce80472938b69eb22783c9f97c30d7bd8be9
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc786257bad753fbb65fde0a94fb9d45ac0e66becd675a5583a0183424ca02e75
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xbc2cc37e42bcd682ca30f74b502bbb0fab9af5df39b1fcb3870e99515a706db4
I've tried to debug these using tenderly.co but it doesn't seem to give any explanation on the error.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Tx was failing because of the value added to the tx here: 'value': w3.toWei(0.0001,'ether')

Comment: Did you remove value and it worked? I'm struggling with a similar issue, but can't get it working

Comment: I set value to 0